# How to add multiple calculated columns to a SparkDataFrame using SparkR?

Tags: r, databricks, azure-databricks, sparkr

Now I'm stuck on a rather basic case, but I can't find a clever solution with `SparkR` ...

From N columns in my SparkDataFrame, I need to create N new calculated columns.

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
   V2 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
   V3 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
   V4 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
   V5 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
   X = runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 5))
sdf <- createDataFrame(df)

sdf <- withColumn(sdf, "V1_X", column("X") / column("V1"))
sdf <- withColumn(sdf, "V2_X", column("X") / column("V2"))
sdf <- withColumn(sdf, "V3_X", column("X") / column("V3"))
sdf <- withColumn(sdf, "V4_X", column("X") / column("V4"))
sdf <- withColumn(sdf, "V5_X", column("X") / column("V5"))
```

Basically, I want to apply a function to my vector/list of columns names.
Easy in R. In SparkR, I am able to `lapply` a function, but I modify the original columns. Something escapes me...!?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider the following approach

```
library(SparkR)
df <- data.frame(V1 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
                 V2 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
                 V3 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
                 V4 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
                 V5 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
                 X = runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 5))

sdf <- createDataFrame(df)
col_Names <- colnames(sdf)
nb_Col_Ratio <- length(col_Names) - 1 

for(i in 1 : nb_Col_Ratio)
{
  new_Col_Name <- paste(col_Names[i], "X")
  sdf <- withColumn(sdf, new_Col_Name, column("X") / column(col_Names[i]))  
}

print(as.data.frame(sdf))
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer doing these kind of tasks using [`SparkR::select`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/reference/select.html) command, instead of looping over multiple [`withColumn`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/reference/withColumn.html) statements. The same logic can be used in Python using Python's list comprehension. See the modified version of your code below:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
   V2 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
   V3 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
   V4 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
   V5 = base::sample(1:10,5), 
   X = runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 5))
sdf <- SparkR::createDataFrame(df)

# sdf <- SparkR::withColumn(sdf, "V1_X", SparkR::column("X") / SparkR::column("V1"))
# sdf <- SparkR::withColumn(sdf, "V2_X", SparkR::column("X") / SparkR::column("V2"))
# sdf <- SparkR::withColumn(sdf, "V3_X", SparkR::column("X") / SparkR::column("V3"))
# sdf <- SparkR::withColumn(sdf, "V4_X", SparkR::column("X") / SparkR::column("V4"))
# sdf <- SparkR::withColumn(sdf, "V5_X", SparkR::column("X") / SparkR::column("V5"))

loop_on_cols <- SparkR::colnames(sdf)[SparkR::colnames(sdf)!="X"]
sdf2 <- SparkR::select(
  sdf,
  c(
    SparkR::colnames(sdf), 
    lapply(
      loop_on_cols, 
      function(c) {
        SparkR::alias(SparkR::column("X")/SparkR::column(c), paste0(c,"_X"))
      }
    )
  )
)
SparkR::head(sdf2)
```